# Font metric-compatible with Calibri Light?

Tags: fonts, font-size

MS's font Calibri is not legally usable outside of MS (and opening a `.doc` document with Libre Office will break the structure of the file). To solve that a new font named Carlito was designed to be compatible with the metric used by Calibri (as reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749466/ms-office-files-looks-different-in-libreoffice) or [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Metric-compatible_fonts) for instance).

Recently, I received a document with a Calibri **light** font in the title, and unfortunately it seems that Carlito's replacement does not work here. Is there a font compatible with Calibri light?

Note that I learnt from Peter Constable that there Calibri light can be [bought legally and used outside of MS](https://fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/calibri-ms), but I would like a font that is open.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not sure where you got that information, but as far as I can tell, there is nothing in the font licence which prohibits the use of Calibri outside of MS (whatever that is supposed to mean). Check the licence for yourself: https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/calibri-ms/licenses#

Comment: The issue with Libre Office is likely something else - either some formatting problem/setting within Libre Office, or a compatibility problem with the .doc format itself.  I use Libre Office myself, and have noticed formatting problems when opening documents created in MS Office. It's certainly less than perfect. Even if you do find a replacement Open font, it may not solve the issue.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks, I'm not sure why Calibri's font seems to allow usage outside of MS now, but I read that a few times in the past (and as far as I understand, it's part of the reason of the creation of Carlito). But in any case I don't want to give 50€ to MS just to edit a document that I got from someone else having this font, so that's why I'd love to have a metric-compatible font that is open and that I can freely use. LO certainly has other formatting issues when trying to reproduce an MS document, but for now my biggest issue is that the fonts that LO used are far from MS's ones.

Comment: Yeah, best not rely on what you have read/heard. There's lots of disinformation on the internet. Always go to the actual licence when checking how you can use a font.  People likely say that because Calibri is installed when you install MS Office - it's "free" if you buy and install their software.  But you can buy it separately without installing MS Office, and use it with any software. In this regard it's no different than any other commercially available font.

Comment: Another weird thing is that a lot of Windows PCs come with a copy of MS Office pre-installed, and even if you don't buy a licence to use Office, the font is still available. As to the legality of using it under such circumstances, that's likely something you'd need to ask a lawyer about.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes true, unfortunately reading licenses are often not that easy when you are not a lawyer ^^ So thanks for pointing that out. Now, anyway, I don't have Windows installed on my system, so I'm still interested in finding a free & open metric-compatible font ;-)